# How to change in rand(?)?

Tags: php

I have a problem by ordering item in my page.
I want the item to be ordered randomly but to change every day.
I use ORDER by rand() code and in the () I want todays date to be displayed.
example if today is 10.12.2020 I want to be in my code ORDER by rand(10).
This is my code

```
include("pagination/function.php");

 $page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
      $limit = 12; //if you want to dispaly 10 records per page then you have to change here
      $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
      $statement = "product  ORDER by rand()"; //you have to pass your query over here


 $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from product {$statement} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
 {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state you want to pass `10` for today, but then the random order will be the same every 10th day of every month every year.  If you want it random every individual day then use the UNIX timestamp:

```
$seed = time();
$statement = "product  ORDER by rand($seed)";
```

If you actually want the day of the month then get the day number:

```
$seed = date("j");
$statement = "product  ORDER by rand($seed)";
```

You might be able to use a [MySQL Date and Time Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) but I have never tried them in `RAND()`.

Comment: I used
      $seed = date("jh");
so day and hour. every day every hour will order them differently.
thank you for showing me how to do it .

Comment: That's fine if that's what you want but then next month on the 10th day at that hour it will have the same random order as today at that hour.

Comment: yes I know it is not a problem because I add new items every week so till next month the list will change.